# use redux with typeScript

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I am a newbie and I just used Redux recently.

Here's my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { controlComponent1 } from "../redux/reduce";

import style from "./style";

const Component1 = (props) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <View
      style={[
        props.style,
        style.container,
        props.show1 ? { backgroundColor: "green" } : null
      ]}
    >
      <Text>show cai nay :v ...</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={style.button} onPress={() => props.chance1}>
        <Text>color</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={style.button}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("component2")}
      >
        <Text> next</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    show1: state.show1
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    chance1: dispatch(controlComponent1)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component1);
```

I know that 2 functions `mapDispatchToProps()` and `mapStateToProps()` are going to make 2 values `chance1` and `show1` becoming props of my component but I do not know how to use it in my component because I am using TypeScript.

I get warnings pictured on these images:

[image: typescript warnings]

[image: typescript warnings]

Can anyone help me to  fix the issue?

Comment: You have to declare the type for `props` as something which included both the expected props and the props added by `connect`.  It is easier to do with the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks, in my opinion.

Comment: can you get take a example, i just work with interface before, like that:
**
interface Props{
    style: object,
    show1: boolean,
    chance1:()=>void,
} 
** 
and add to component like: 
** const Component1 = (props: Props ) =>{} **
i have never used useSelector and useDispatch before

Answer (score 0):

You can get your props type if you seprate your connection in two steps, so as to have a spare const to infer the type from like this:

```
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
type Props = ConnectedProps<typeof connector> //your props type

export default connector(Component1)
```

Then to use your component:

```
const Component1 = (props:Props) => {}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have learned hooks and solve my problem with useDispatch and useSelector, it is realy simple, do you think i should use Hook to replace mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps ?

Comment: according to my understanding of react which is not that much, I would use hooks for short or not to big apps to handle encapsulated states along the flow down of your component hierarchy. If that goes out of control and you need to communicate with your componenet along their "horizontal" hierarchy (not from parent to children), you can try [unstated](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated). If this "horizontal communication" is happening all the time and between very "far away in the hierarchy" components and your app gets big, then I you would use react.redux.

Comment: Another case of use of redux is where the hierarchy of components is very large, so even the component communication might not be horizontal, you might need to pass a prop to a child very deep down in the hierarchy through lots of components which do not need that prop for nothing else than to pass it through. That is known as prop "drilling". In that case you can also check for hooks alternatives :)

Answer (score 0):

Your component needs to know what props it is receiving in order to access them.  So we need to declare a type for the component's props which includes the props that are added by the Redux `connect` as well as the props that you will pass to the component when you call it.

You can either assign a type directly to the `props` like `= (props: Component1Props) =>` or assign the `React.FunctionComponent<Props>` / `React.FC<Props>` type to the component with the right props, like `const Component1: FunctionComponent<Component1Props> = (props) =>`

It is a lot easier to get typescript support when using `useSelector` and `useDispatch` in your component rather than `connect`.  And [this is the recommended approach](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#recommendations).

#### With Hooks

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, ViewStyle } from "react-native";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { controlComponent1 } from "../redux/reduce";
import style from "./style";
import { RootState } from "./path/store";
// ^ some type for your app's specific state type

interface Component1Props {
  // own props
  style?: ViewStyle;
}

const Component1: FunctionComponent<Component1Props> = (props) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  // type will be automatically inferred if `RootState` is correct
  const show1 = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.show1);

  // we don't map dispatch the same way with hooks
  // we get access to the dispatch function and then call it
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <View
      style={[
        props.style,
        style.container,
        show1 ? { backgroundColor: "green" } : null
      ]}
    >
      <Text>show cai nay :v ...</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={style.button}
        // call dispatch with the action from your action creator
        onPress={() => dispatch(controlComponent1())}
      >
        <Text>color</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={style.button}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("component2")}
      >
        <Text> next</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Component1;
```

#### With Connect

```
import React, {FunctionComponent} from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, ViewStyle } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {Dispatch} from "redux";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { controlComponent1 } from "../redux/reduce";
import style from "./style";
import {RootState} from "./path/store";
// ^ some type for your app's specific state type

interface Component1Props {
  // own props
  style?: ViewStyle;
  // from mapStateToProps
  show1: boolean;
  // from mapDispatchToProps
  chance1: () => void;
}

const Component1: FunctionComponent<Component1Props> = (props) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <View
      style={[
        props.style,
        style.container,
        props.show1 ? { backgroundColor: "green" } : null
      ]}
    >
      <Text>show cai nay :v ...</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={style.button} onPress={() => props.chance1}>
        <Text>color</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={style.button}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("component2")}
      >
        <Text> next</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state: RootState) {
  return {
    show1: state.show1
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch) {
  return {
    // if this is an action creator then you need to call it!
    chance1: dispatch(controlComponent1())
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component1);
```

Comment: I have used Hooks to resolve my problem, it is easier. I have tried using connect as your advice but it have a error: 
Argument of type 'FunctionComponent<Component1Props>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<{ show1: boolean; } & { chance1: { type: actionType; }; }, Component1Props>>'.